# Multilanguage routing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, multilingual

I want to make multilanguage website and I want to use React to make user's panel. In order to translate component I'll use react.i18next but how I can translate routing? Look at this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/about">About</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/user/1">User</NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-8">

              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route path="/user/:id" component={User} />
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
      </Router>
```

It simple routing system but depending on checked language I want that reouting directed to "/user/:id" in english language or"/uzytkownik/:id" in polish language. Any idea how I can do that?